# User property is Null

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Why User property is Null on ApiController when in the same time it's filled with logined user's info on the MVC Controller (AccountController or HomeController)? All of this applied on default VS2013 update 2 SPA template. What should I do to get current user data?

Comment: what code do you have?

Comment: I do the next steps: 1) Create SPA project 2) Add API controller (read/write) 3) Change Get method to this, where user is null on breakpoint ``// GET: api/User/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            return user;
        }``

Comment: What are you using the id parameter for?

Comment: It's key for working in another database. MongoDB.